# Ultrahook and MAMP PRO 4.0.5 in Codeigniter on Mac El Capitan

Tags: php, ruby, rubygems, codeigniter-3, webhooks

I have successfully installed ultrahook.
I had to install this in usr/local/bin on Mac El Capitan, because I was not able (due to the new security policy) to install it in usr/bin.

When I run the command:

```
ultrahook <my.namespace>  https://localhost:8890
```

I get this message:

```
Authenticated as <namespace_name>
Forwarding activated...
http://<namespace_name>.ultrahook.com ->https://localhost:8890
```

So it seems that everything is up and running.

But when I send a test notification from Stripe via this above mentioned webhook the following error will show in the terminal:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:878:in `initialize': getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known (SocketError)
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:878:in `open'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:878:in `block in connect'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/timeout.rb:52:in `timeout'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:877:in `connect'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:862:in `do_start'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:851:in `start'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:1373:in `request'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:1396:in `send_entity'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:1184:in `post'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/ultrahook-0.1.4/lib/ultrahook/client.rb:127:in `http_post'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/ultrahook-0.1.4/lib/ultrahook/client.rb:116:in `process_request'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/ultrahook-0.1.4/lib/ultrahook/client.rb:90:in `process'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/ultrahook-0.1.4/lib/ultrahook/client.rb:160:in `block (3 levels) in init_stream'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/protocol.rb:411:in `call_block'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/protocol.rb:402:in `<<'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/protocol.rb:106:in `read'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http/response.rb:313:in `read_chunked'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http/response.rb:276:in `block in read_body_0'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http/response.rb:269:in `inflater'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http/response.rb:274:in `read_body_0'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http/response.rb:201:in `read_body'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/ultrahook-0.1.4/lib/ultrahook/client.rb:155:in `block (2 levels) in init_stream'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:1419:in `block (2 levels) in transport_request'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http/response.rb:162:in `reading_body'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:1418:in `block in transport_request'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:1409:in `catch'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:1409:in `transport_request'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:1382:in `request'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/ultrahook-0.1.4/lib/ultrahook/client.rb:153:in `block in init_stream'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:852:in `start'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:582:in `start'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/ultrahook-0.1.4/lib/ultrahook/client.rb:148:in `init_stream'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/ultrahook-0.1.4/lib/ultrahook/client.rb:65:in `start'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/ultrahook-0.1.4/bin/ultrahook:6:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/bin/ultrahook:22:in `load'
    from /usr/local/bin/ultrahook:22:in `<main>'
```

I have never used ruby or ruby gems before, so I can not figure out what all this means and how to solve this issue.

Any help will be much appreciated

Thanks

In the mean while I have tried a lot of combinations but this error persists after the registration of the endpoint:

```
ultrahook stripe http://site-gen:8888/stripe19440207
Authenticated as bootsweaver
Forwarding activated...
http://stripe.bootsweaver.ultrahook.com -> http://site-gen:8888/stripe19440207
```

Getting the response it remain just the same:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:878:in `initialize': getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known (SocketError)
```

Please help me out with this, I am busy with this  from yesterday already and I have not idea of this all means.

I can not go on with my work and I am stuck.

Thank you guys

Answer (score 2):

Ok! It took two days to figure out what was going wrong and now everything is working correctly.

So, as a dedicated SO user i feel that I must share what I have found out.

First think to be mentioned is that ruby has a very general way to
report the generated errors and if you don't know nothing (as I do)
about ruby then you have a problem .

Even thought I had a look at the ruby code by the complaining method `initialize` and I found out that noting was wrong with that.

I am on Mac El Capitan and using MAMP PRO 4.0.5 as my local server and Codeigniter 3 as framework and I want to use ultrahook in order to test the Stripe webhook events locally before everithing goes in production.

The first thing to be aware is the MAMP configuration.
If you are planning to use ultrahook and want install it take care that this checkbox option (located under the Ryby tab on the left) is unchecked:

```
Make ruby available in the command line
```

Why?

If you install ultrahook with this option checked, the gem will be installed in:

```
/Applications/MAMP/Library/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems
```

And you don't want that. You normally would install it in the usr/bin

Now. at this time, due to the new security policy El Capitan do not allow you to write in this folder. What we do now?

Just install it in in the usr/local/bin.

```
$ gem install -n /usr/local/bin ultrahook
```

Once done you will be able to do the normal stuff explained in the http://www.ultrahook.com/. I am sorry but I would like to explain to you the complete process but it will go out the scope of this post.

At this point you will than be able to use ultrahook and to register your webhook by Stripe.

The last important thing is to exclude the controller you are using (the page which will respond to the Stripe webhook events)
to be blocked by the csrf protection.

```
$config['csrf_exclude_uris'] = array('stripe/webhook');
```

Or whatever you have defined in your $route[''].

If you forget to do this you will get a 403 response, which means `forbidden`.

The other important thing is, when you are checking the Stripe response you need to be in the terminal where you are requesting the connection through your ultrahook namespace in order to see the incoming event sent to you.

I hope this will help someone having hard time trying to make this work.

If you have any additional question I will be glad to help you out.